# Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Project:processDebugManifest'

Tags: manifest

Today in Android Studio, I rebuild the project and I got this error.
The project was fine prior to rebuild. I didn't change anything in my code.

Error was

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Project:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

In `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}
```

Is it a kind of `SDK/Libraries` error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does your project depend on any other libraries? If so, you might want make sure the build.gradle and AndroidManifest match up with the project's sdk versions

[Gradle: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest)