# gradle: Execution failed for task ':myApp:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have am really stumped...

I have an Android Studio (version 1.4) project consisting of two modules - androidLVL and myApp. When I attempt to build the project (Build -> Rebuild Project) I get these messages:

```
:myApp:processDebugManifest FAILED

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myApp:processDebugManifest'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Previous [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest) indicate the error can be caused by incompatible sdk version numbers in the gradle build files - but I can't figure out what the correct versions should be. I edited the build files, but to no avail. Can someone please help? Here are the two gradle build files:

androidLVL:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    // compileSdkVersion 22
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8'
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'
}
```

myApp:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8'
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tomoreilly.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':androidLVL')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/htmllexer.jar')
    // compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3"

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
}
```

(Re the error message suggestion to 'run with --stacktrace option' etc. - I do not know how to invoke these options from within Android Studio).

Comment: i think you need to comment `compileSdkVersion 22` in _myApp_ gradle

Comment: pRaNaY - thanks, I just tried that and get over 100 errors similar to this: "Error:(44, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCutDrawable'."

Comment: please uncomment `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3` in _myApp_ gradle

Comment: Uncommented, and get 189 errors like this: "Error:(46, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModePasteDrawable'."