# 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

I am getting error while trying to run the app,

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugMainDexClassList'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   This is my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}

android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.aranea-apps.android.libs:android-logger:1.0.10'
compile 'com.rosaloves:bitlyj:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.aranea-apps.android.libs:android-async-runners:1.0.0'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2'
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.1'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-async:4.0.1'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-stream:4.0.1'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-media-support:4.0.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.1'

compile(name: 'app-1.3.9', ext: 'aar')
compile(name: 'swipelistview', ext: 'aar')
compile files('libs/rest-client-1.3.5.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
compile project(':MuPDF')
compile project(':ZxingLib')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest

Comment: Thanks, Checked all of this but doesn't work for me

Comment: minSdkVersion 21 --> 15
targetSdkVersion 24 --> 23 ps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest