# Android Studio 2.1 Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, r.java-file

Android Studio 2.1, 
Java V8 Update 91, Gradle 2.1.0 .

I know that this questions has been asked many times here, but none of the recommendation solutions works out.

In a sudden after compiling ready to run on Emulator, my IDE give an error at the R.id attribute. Every  Java files suddenly give the same error even I don't make any changes to the file.

I tried to make a new project, see if things different but the error keep coming. In my mind it could be internal error, again. Even I just update my IDE just now.

The Java file;

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_science);

    list_View = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.maintable); 
    String[] Days = new String[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    dayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(Days));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dayList);
    list_View.setAdapter(adapter);

    NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    if (nfc.isEnabled()) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dayList);
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC turned ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn On NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

The `R` is the error.

XML file that associate to the Java;

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/maintable"
    >
</ListView>
```

Is this, again, an internal error?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the entire class file containing your `R` problems. Note that your Java stack trace has nothing to do with your app, let alone your `R` issue.

Comment: Done edited the java.

Comment: That is not the entire class file containing your `R` problems.

Comment: What do you mean ? Is it the R.java file?

Comment: I mean that there are more lines in the Java file that contains that `onCreate()` method. I did not suggest that you post a few more lines. I suggested that you post **the entire class file**.

Comment: Yeah, just those in my onCreate() method. You mean the whole Java file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to change the Gradle version from 2.1.0 to 2.0.0, even in AS ver 2.1, ignoring the Instant Run performance and its work out. The little R error is now gone. Now, I tried to change back to 2.1.0, the R error also gone..!!
Sometime this little thing drive me crazy, a bit.

Shame on me.

Answer (score 12):

Try syncing the project, go to Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files

**UPDATE**

If you're using Android Studio 3.3, use the `Sync Project with Gradle Files` icon

[image]

Comment: Try also to clean the project: Build > Clean Project. If the error persist, then you probably have a syntax error in one of your XML files.

Comment: I've done that, in fact the project synced when we start the IDE.

Comment: @InfiniteLoops  Does sync fail? Do you get any useful error message?

Comment: It says, **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs**

Comment: @InfiniteLoops: That would be why your `R` class is not being generated.

Comment: @InfiniteLoops Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest

Answer (score 2):

I have just gone through this nightmare. Ended up removing all xml code to notepad until it was fixed. Then reintroduced sections of code until problem appeared.
Thinking back, it all started when I pasted some code using WordPad. Apparently WordPad contains a different coding or something so bet to avoid. 
Anyway just check your white space in xml by deleting it all to rid yourself of any hidden characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try performing a clean and rebuild by going to `Build > Clean Project` and `Build > Make Project`

Comment: still, didn't resolve. Still says the error like the one I reply above.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the R.java class is not created  when there is some error into an xml file (like activity_main.xml). For example, if you change some **attribute name** that has a reserved word that cannot be changed.
Like this: if you changed the attribute called: **id** to another name like
**id_A_Word_With_Error_Here** in this  code  that can be part of the activity_main.xml, your error (R class not created) can occur.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
```

and there is an error like:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id_A_Word_With_Error_Here="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
```

If clean, rebuild did not work and there is no error with import like  `import com.something...` , my suggestion is to search an error into xml files.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem many times. The right solution is:

When you type `R`, the Android Studio will give you many different namespaces for `R` to choose from, that look like `R(***.***.***)`, but what you really need is the namespace that ends with `***.myProject`. (Note: myProject is your project name), e.g: `R(com.example.milka.demoProject)`.

If you choose any other namespace, you will get the error message, so you have to delete the unneeded `import`, and re-choose your `R`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error may cause for the tools, trying install Android SDK Build Tools from Tools > Android > SDK Manager.
or maybe this error can be caused by adding an activity to a namespace that is different to the root, you can trying >>Import com.example.MyApplication.R;
or your also can clean o rebuild your project in Build > Clean Project or Build > Rebuild Project

Answer (score -1):

If you are using google play services and your compilesdk version is lower than 23 then download the new sdk and update your compile version. After that try cleaning and rebuilding. It will be fixed

Comment: Sorry but I'm not using GPService.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Rebuild Project go to 
*Build> Rebuild Project*
and perform it without doing the Clean project
I had the same problem & it worked for me

Comment: Nope. I did clean, rebuild, and sync... Look at my own answer below.