# Android Studio : cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio is reporting that is cannot resolve symbol R.

I already performed clean project, rebuild project, analysed and inspected code  but it does not resolve the "**cannot resolve symbol R**" error in Android Studio.

How can I fix this? Please help me.

Comment: Have you [searched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio) stack overflow for [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but) [issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920879/android-studio-2-1-cannot-resolve-symbol-r)?

Comment: Post the screenshot of ur error and try to see if the error appears in just one activity or in every activity

Answer (score 1):

First check is there any error in any xml layout or not. If yes, then resolve it first.

Otherwise remove junit dependency from project and rebuild the project.

for more information : https://androidpugnator.wordpress.com/2017/03/30/deal-with-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio/

[image]

Comment: thanks , now my project are preety without red .