# Error when add library notification handler

Tags: android, azure, push-notification

I added azure notification  follow [azurenotification](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-push/)

But when I added

```html
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.4@aar'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
```

And run app it have error

```html
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-43
 is also present at [com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-107:19 to override.
```

here is build.gradle

```html
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile files('libs/ads28112016.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
    }
}
```

My Manifest
[image]
How I can fix it? thank you very much

Comment: can you post your manifest file?

Comment: @sasikumar I added it

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest

Comment: I have the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Removing...

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

On the manifest. It seems Microsoft defined an icon on their library conflicting with yours. This is probably fixed now... The error states that cleary

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-43
>       is also present at [com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-107:19 to override.