# problems building APK using android studio app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android-studio

when I try to build the APK project like this
[image]

It shows me this error message :

[image: errors APK]

help me please.
Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `minSDK version` to a higher level. See if that's work.
You can look here for more details:

[Gradle: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest)

Comment: Moisoni lonut/ thank you very much for your help i will try