# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

**i don't know why this error arises suddenly it came in my stackrace**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
        is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
```

Manifest file:

this is my manifest file, i had updated my android studio 2.3.2 recently.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.shopkart.theinvincible.shopkart">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Your support version defined in manifest file is `25.3.1` while you are using  a support library with version `26.0.0`.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: First post here your manifest file.

Comment: have a look at manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a version conflict in with the support library you used and the support version defined in your merged manifest file. You should add `<meta-data>` tag in your manifest file as shown below in order to override the conflict.(This is clearly mentioned in suggestion along with error log, see it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.shopkart.theinvincible.shopkart">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data tools:replace="android:value"/>

        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: try using support library with lower version.

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: in similar manner you used `support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1`

Comment: @AvadaKedavra so my solution isn't helped you? But you marked as answer to the same code?

Answer (score 1):

the Manifests have different `SDK` Versions and cannot be merged
 you needed to edit `Manifests`.[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest) may help you

Answer (score 0):

use this below code or go back to the older version to continue your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.shopkart.theinvincible.shopkart">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data tools:replace="android:value"/>

        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```