# I have an Android Manifest merger issue, pointing me to update to 26.1.0. I try and it says that that package is not available

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, manifest, build-tools

This is the error that I get:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':passenger:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

And I changed my build.gradle from:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.1.0'
```

And this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:transition:26.0.2'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:transition:26.1.0'
```

I get an "Install build tools 26.1.0 and sync project. And when I press on it, I get an "Packages unavailable" error:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/Bt1tHrYh5Hk4LZe/upload.png

How can it "find" a package in my project that has 26.1.0 if there is no 26.1.0?

Comment: try buildTools 27.0.3

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest?rq=1

Comment: go to settings>Appearance & behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > under platfrom select and Apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the below image, there is no **26.1.0** version of build tools available

**[image: 26.1.0]**
**Try choosing some other available version**

Comment: Thanks, I just moved the android.support libraries to 26.1.0 and left the build tools to 26.0.2 and it worked like that