# Tensorflow-Lite Code-lab doesn't work with build-tool 3.2.0-alpha05

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, android-gradle-plugin

Sample project of tf-lite works with 3.0.1 but not at 3.2.0-alpha05, maybe 3.1.0 RC(not tried)

Please checkout this problem at 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/index.html#7

```
.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/tensorflow-lite-0.1.1.aar/092814ba6530796fca8e7fc3596f1aa2/AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-6:12 Error:
        Missing 'package' declaration in manifest at [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.1.1] AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-6:12
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74173626

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround:
Goto "Merged Manifest" in Android Studio as explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41889558/9570311
Then click on [tensorflow-lite:0.1 manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2si1.png) and add **org.tensorflow.lite** as package:
[package="org.tensorflow.lite"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfQ0O.png)