# Android Build error [ app:processDebugManifest ]

Tags: android, android-studio

Problem :
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.1.0).

As per Studio suggestion, added `tools:replace="android:value"` to `<meta-data>` element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

it did not work.

AndroidManifest File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.rahul.my_addmobdemo"
    tools:replace="26.1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle File :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rahul.my_addmobdemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.1.0).

`customtabs` support library is the Google play services 15 dependency, so you need to add it to your dependencies block. Don't forget to make the same version with your support library:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    // you can also remove this because it's automatically added
    // by Google play services dependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'

    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}
```

then remove `tools:replace="26.1.0"` because you don't need it.

After that, update your `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and support libraries to use the same version which is version 26.

Comment: Thanks a Lot...Your Solution Worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are incompatibility beteween versions 25 against 26

Try as follow

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0" //or 26.0.2 if required

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 26
        ...
    }
}
...
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Abner,
Thanks for immediate response.
I tried your suggestion but ended in same error.
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rahul.my_addmobdemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
  
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
}

Answer (score 0):

Override the `<application>` tag in your manifest like this to correctly enable the tools:replace function

```
<application
    tools:replace="android:value"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, Thanks for the fast response.I Tried your solution, still it didnt work.
Ended in getting below error.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs