# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' in first project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[I just Installed Everything for flutter...and run the first default app...but this problem is showing] Like picture below:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').

> File 'E:\Program Future\Flutter\Flutter\anualproject\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Please help me !. I also find any solution in internet but don't result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest

Answer (score 2):

Just edit :

android/build.gradle 4.?.? -> 4.0.2

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

and :

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties 6.?.?-all -> 6.4.1-all

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

This problems doesnt occur if you save your project in the C drive. I dont know why this behaviour, but it works!

Comment: whenever you get the flutter gradle problem try to give the flutter doctor status, that will help others.

Comment: flutter doctor doesnt show any issue, beside that flutter doctor is the very basic approach and isnt useful in this issue

Answer (score 0):

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').

> File 'E:\task ajay\Flutter Apps\flutter_application_1\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 47s
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             50.6s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

ans:-
android/build.gradle 4.?.? -> 4.0.2

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

and :

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties 6.?.?-all -> 6.4.1-all

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip