# please someone help me with this error .Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMibA.png)

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @67bd4443

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: share your Manifest file

Comment: check this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest