# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'. VS code

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and am trying to run a new project on VS code.

installed the latest flutter at 19/1/2022. `flutter --version` gives me 2.8.1.
jdk is 17.0.1

this is what i get ...

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N975F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'G:\1-programing\Projects\Flutter\flutter_application_2\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\username\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

tried to change gradle, which is 6.7 in **gradle-wrapper.properties**, to 7.3.3 which is the latest.
and this is what i get...

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N975F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @30206a4d
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

i have tried changing the build.gradle in android/app/src

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_application_2"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

to

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gfgpagination"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
```

and it was not helpfull.
have tried searching these errors but i could not use them to this day.

my build.gradle in android folder

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my build.gradle in android/app folder

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_application_2"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

soooo, I am going to answer my own question.
it seems i was using the latest java SDK version.

As mentioned in the install web page, i must have downloaded java SDK8 .
that's probably everything i did to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for last error '**Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path**'  : `https://exerror.com/accessible-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module/`

Comment: I tried Downgrading to 16.0.1 and 15.0.2 and none of them made any noticible changes beside changing "@30206a4d" this number.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Manifest.xml` add below line if it is not present:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
```

For more further information you will visit below link

[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest)

Comment: I have 3 AndroidManifest.xml in debug/main/profile. can you help me by saying where should i put it? Iam not familiar with htese HTML like lines.

Comment: i added it to main/manifest.xml. <application> Here </application>.
it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: What's your build.gradle file? Can you please describe here?

Comment: thanks, I put the code in build.gradle files in my question.