# Does react-native support jdk 17?

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, gradle

So I have been having some problems with launching the initial react-native template project on android. And after consulting someone I was told that jdk 17 is not supported. But I really don't want to downgrade as this could break other things that I already have and work with. To be specific this is the error I get:

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
11 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 9 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @7ec6bc9b

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. 

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081


* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @7ec6bc9b

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s

    at makeError (C:\Users\karti\Desktop\ShoppingList\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\karti\Desktop\ShoppingList\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\karti\Desktop\ShoppingList\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\karti\Desktop\ShoppingList\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

I have looked at this already and nothing worked.
[Gradle: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I solved this issue by installing JDK 16 on my system and everything is solved and running fine. I don't know if the problem was with Gradle or JDK or react-native but hope that in the future jdk 17 is supported.

If you have the same issue then you can go to:
[jdk 16](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk16-archive-downloads.html)

1)Download and Install the JDK 16.

2)Add the path to your jdk in the PATH in your system environment variable.

3)Open cmd and do `java -version` you should see something like

```
java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I follow your configuration and it works now thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To know if this is a java version-related issue, You need to check your Gradle version.

currently only Gradle version 7.3 support java 17.

You can check [gradle compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) to check.

you can check your version with the command line by typing `gradlew.bat -version`

If your Gradle is version 7.3 then it has nothing to do with the JDK version.

Comment: I do have Gradle version 7.3.3 installed and working correctly.

Comment: It seems that Gradle is throwing this error bcz I can't build my project.

Answer (score 0):

For me react native didnt work successfully with OpenJdk 17. Was getting error building apk

For me the problem got fixed with installing OpenJdk 11.