# The exception of flutter project is Execution failed for task app:processProfileMainManifest

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am running a flutter project. I may have a exception about gradle build. The exception is as follow.

My env is Flutter 2.10.2, Java 11, android-studio-2022.2.1.20-windows, gradle 7.5.1.

```
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source! Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in profile mode... Running Gradle task 'assembleProfile'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processProfileMainManifest'. Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @2f4c843a

Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s Exception: Gradle task assembleProfile failed with exit code 1
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:401:9) <asynchronous suspension>
#2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:184:5) <asynchronous suspension>
#3      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:574:7) <asynchronous suspension>
#4      FlutterDevice.runCold (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:523:33) <asynchronous suspension>
#5      ColdRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_cold.dart:57:28) <asynchronous suspension>
#6      AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:645:9) <asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppDomain.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:643:5) <asynchronous suspension>
#8      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:621:15) <asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1287:27) <asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19) <asynchronous suspension>
#11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13) <asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9) <asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19) <asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5) <asynchronous suspension>
#15     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9) <asynchronous suspension>
#16     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19) <asynchronous suspension>
#17     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3) <asynchronous suspen
```

I should how to fix.

I try to set the env of the project as gradle 7.5.1, but the exception is not fix.

Comment: Try flutter clean and pub get

Comment: It is useless. I am confused.

Comment: * flutter pub cache clean
* flutter clean
* flutter pub cache repair
* flutter pub get

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest